# vtd-xml: Autopilot: registering a function in Autopilot

Tags: vtd-xml

Java VTD-XML has the following API

```
class AutoPilot{
    declareVariableExpr(java.lang.String varName, java.lang.String varExpr);
}
```

how can i register a function in the VTD-XML Autopilot?

for example i want to evaluate the following expression:

```
concat("abc-",getCurrentDateTime());
```

i want the Autopilot to let me register a function called `getCurrentDateTime()` and let me use it in the expression evaluation.

how to register a function in Autopilot? If yes, can you please point me to some examples?

Regards,

VImal

Comment: I dont think vtd-xml offer this feature yet...

Comment: thanks. can you please write this as an answer? i will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

VTD-XML does not allow you to define a function to be used in the XPath evaluation... this however sounds like an interesting feature to be considered in v 2.13